# Pass different type as activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have several activities that need to perform HTTP requests (send a JSON request a get another JSON object back).

My idea was to share one AsyncTask for all these requests. I am passing the Activity as a parameter so that I can call method once the execution of the request is finished.

I would like to pass one more parameter to my AsyncTask that would be the class of my Activity (MainActivity.class, SecondActivity.class) and then use that information to cast the Activity to the correct type and then later call on the method (would be the same method name for all activities).

I could also create an interface with my call back method, but I am not sure if I that would work neither.

Could this work or is my approach wrong here ?

Thanks for your feed-back.

My code:

public class HTTPReq extends AsyncTask {

```
private MainActivity callerActivity;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String data = (String) params[0];
    String cookie = (String) params[1];
    callerActivity = (MainActivity) params[2];

...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    callerActivity.ProcessHTTPReqAnswer(result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Aswins answer isn't terrible but it's still not the most efficient way.

Declare an Interface that has a method for callback. Pass an instance of that interface to your asynctask then have the async task invoke it if its there as per my examples below

Interface:

```
  public interface IMyCallbackInterface {
     void onCallback(String result);
  }
```

Async Task:

```
  public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<..., String> {

      private IMyCallbackInterface mCallback;


      public MyAsyncTask(..., IMyCallbackInterface callback) {
           mCallback = callback;
      }

      protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
         ....
      } 

      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         if (mCallback != null) {
              mCallback.onCallback(result);
         }
      }
```

Activity:

```
     public MyActivity extends Activity {

          private void someMethod(){
               new MyAsyncTask(..., new IMyCallbackInterface() {

                     public void onCallback(String result) {
                           //TODO use the result to do whatever i need
                           //I have access to my aactivity methods and member variables here
                     }
               }.execute();
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a wrong approach to do it like that. You should use BroadcastReceiver. Once a AsyncTask is done, sent the result out as a Broadcast. Each of the activity will be listen to the results they are interested in. This way no one needs to keep a reference to the activity which is dangerous.

Here is an example.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("result1");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getSupportActivity()).registerReceiver(new CustomBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
```

In the AsyncTask, do this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("result1").putExtra(
                "data", result);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getSupportActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Back in the activity, do this

```
private class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if ("result1".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            String result = bundle.getString("data");
            // Process the result here.
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: My Asynctask is defined in a separate class, so that I can call it from different activites. I cannot use the "getSupportActivity()" to get the main activity, I need to pass a "Context" object to the Asyntask and it then works fine.